# Block user upon one webform submission

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm using Drupal 8, and I'm trying to block a user after submitting a certain webform. I have the below scenario:

- Only authenticated user can submit and use the webform
- Webform submission is limited to once per user
- Users can save drafts of the webform and continue filling it later on
- Rules action or otherwise should take place when the user has logged in

I tried to use Rules with rules_webform module but to no avail. The actions in rules are all there, but I need a condition to detect if the user has submitted the webform completely, not saved it as a draft only.

Appreciate any help given

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to write your own webform handler and attach it to the webform's `postSave()` method. You can also experiment and try another method if needed from `WebformHandlerBase`.

Webform handlers are not documented well, but they should be because they are quite useful.

**modules/custom/mymodule/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/MyModuleWebformHandler.php**

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;

/**
 * Webform example handler.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "mymodule_webform_handler",
 *   label = @Translation("My Module Webform Handler"),
 *   category = @Translation("My Module"),
 *   description = @Translation("Block users after submission"),
 *   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
 *   results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 *   submission = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::SUBMISSION_OPTIONAL,
 * )
 */

class MyModuleWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase
{

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function postSave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webformSubmission, $update = TRUE)
  {
    if (!$webformSubmission->isDraft()) {
      $webformSubmission->getOwner()->block();
    }
  }

}
```

After getting that setup, enable your new module (don't forget an info.yml file) and then edit your webform settings > handlers to add this to that particular form.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your swift reply, I did what you suggested and handler showed in the settings->handlers, but it didn't take effect, is there anything i'm missing here?

Comment: never mind, it worked, thank you so much

Comment: Hi again, just wanted to point out that the code above also happen on 'save draft' not just on the final submission. I didn't find a condition to make the above code happen on the final submission only, i'm still trying to figure it out, cheers...

Comment: done, the code to check if it's a draft or not is $webformSubmission->isDraft()

Comment: Thanks I updated the answer. I usually disable drafts so this wasn't something I ran into.